# Stop Vimeo video with javascript - inside a loop and using a modal window

Tags: api, video-player, vimeo

Good night everyone,
im trying to make a vimeo video stop when a  tag are clicked. A modal window are called inside a "while loop". I found a code that use the vimeo api (http://jsfiddle.net/joan_r/dutzh512/) but this works only in my first video, the others doesn't stop when the  tag are clicked.

This is how my code are going:

```
    <script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>

    <?php

    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'orderby'   => 'date',
        'paged' => $paged
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

        $slug = $post->post_name;

        $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true); 

        ?>

        <a href="#<?php echo $slug ?>" rel="modal">
            <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { echo $thumb_url[0]; } ?>)">
                <p class="legenda"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            </div>
        </a>

        <div class="window" id="<?php echo $slug ?>">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <a class="stop" href="#">STOP</a>           
        </div>

       <script> 

            var iframe = $('.video-player')[0];
            var player = $f(iframe);

            $('.stop').click(function() {
                //alert('stoped');
                player.api('unload');
            });

        </script> 

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?> 

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

This are working, but only in the first video. What im doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution:

```
        <script> 

            jQuery("#mascara").click(function() { 
                $('.video-player').each(function(index) {
                    $(this)[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"method":"unload"}','*');


                });
            });

        </script>
```